# Encrypting in Eloquent Model with AES_ENCRYPT

Tags: mysql, encryption, laravel-5, aes

Laravel has a built in Crypt class that allows encryption. The key is associated to the app and can be changed per request using something like:

```
$key = env('DEV_CACHE_KEY', 'DEV_CHANGE');
Crypt::setKey($key); // sets to new key
$action->descr = Crypt::encrypt($request->descr);
Crypt::setKey(Config::get('app.key')); // resets key to app
$action->save()
```

We save our data using a Memcached key that is saved on a specific server. This is set to be retrieved through the Memcached class, but for now I am using a defined key that is saved to the app environment. The defined key is used in MySQLs `AES_DECRYPT()` to decrypt the data that is saved. We are trying to keep backwards compatibility so I need to be able to do something like MySQLs `AES_ENCRYPT()`.

The above code doesn't work because when I go to decrypt with below it returns empty.

```
$ynak = env('DEV_CACHE_KEY', 'DEV_CHANGE');;

return DB::connection('action_table')
    ->table('action AS a')
    ->select('a.*', DB::raw('AES_DECRYPT(`descr`, "'.$ynak.'") as `descr`'), DB::raw('(status LIKE "%completed%" OR status LIKE "%closed%") as isClosed'));
```

The way the table is set up is a bit bad as I inherited it, but I'm not allowed to make changes.

Is there a way to use `Crypt::encrypt` to equal a MySQL `AES_ENCRYPT`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a successful way to do this the way I'm asking. If another user posts an answer that can I will accept it, but this is my workaround.

Create a new instance of the model in some way. All ways are acceptable. It should just create the model and save into the database.

At that point you'll have an id (you should have an autoincrement id to reference).

```
$action = new Action();
...
$action->save();

$id = $action->id;
$key = env('DEV_CACHE_KEY', 'DEV_CHANGE');
DB::connection('action_table')->table('action')->where('id', '=', $id)->update([
    'descr' => DB::raw('AES_ENCRYPT("'.$request->descr.'", "'.$key.'")')
]);
```

This will do the AES encrypt as required and will create the new action. The only problem is that you cannot use `$action->descr` to successfully display the saved text / encrypted text. I do not need that ability so that does not matter as much.